# Unresolved function or method on()

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

This code runs in the server. I am making a simple websocket on the server and it looks for connections made to it. However, IntelliJ does not recognize the `on()` method that has been called on io. I am using IntelliJ latest version and coding in Node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

function onRequest(req,res)
{
    console.log('User requested for page: ',req.url);
}

// create a middleware application
var app = express();
app.use(onRequest);

// serve static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(4000);

// setup the socket on the server
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection',function(socket)
{
    console.log('Socket id is: ',socket.id);
});
```

Comment: `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries > Download > socket.io`

Comment: do not use `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries > Download` for .js files in IDEA IDEs, it will hide Predefined Node.js Core deps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `npm install @types/socket.io`. It will add the necessary definition file.

Comment: To me, this is the correct answer. Saving it as dev dependency makes the project work for any IDE with TS support, not just intelliJ's. So, @S.Chakraborty, you may want to think about marking this answer as the right one?